# jcl to find the whole size of given n datasets

Tags: mainframe, zos, jcl

I need to find the whole size (in TRACKS) of the given n datasets. For example, if there are 15000 datasets under user1.* , I should get the value by adding all the 15000 dataset's size.
Is there any command / jcl which can do the above mentioned calculation?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just talk to your Storage techs. This will be a massive waste of processing time. Your Storage people will already have reports and information and if they want you to be able to do this yourself, they will tell you how. Remember, on the Mainframe, someone, somewhere is likely paying for the CPU/IO usage, so don't just go off doing things like this, it'll lead to a visit from someone somewhere along the way, wearing a frown, and wanting to know why you've done such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

The LISTDSI command (in REXX) return info on a specific dataset including size, you can loop on your datasets and sum the results. 
Also, I remember it has an issue with multivolumns datasets so kep an eye out.
if you dont know how to get the list, you can uss DFDSS or other options ([Similar question](http://www.ibmmainframes.com/viewtopic.php?t=31802&highlight=lmdlist))